# SQL Server not releasing memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one question about SQL Server memory usage.

When I start my SQL Server, it starts consuming memory and as the time goes (2-3 hours) `sqlservr.exe` process consumes all the memory, leaving just 100 MB free for windows operations.

I have seen in the perfmon, the counter "SQL Server:Memory counter" shows only 5% of usage.
So why the `sqlservr.exe` consumes all the memory even if it is using only 5% of it?

What I want to do is `sqlservr.exe` to consume memory as per its need, not in advance. And I also don't want to put limit on "max server memory".

Thank you all

Comment: SQL Server is designed predominantly to live on a server installation by itself - so it's designed to be greedy with memory. max server memory is about the only widget that MS provide to you to reign in this behaviour.

Comment: SQL Server will use all the memory it can get - **unless** you limit it by specifying a `max server memory` setting. So **either** you put a limit in there, or you live with the fact it'll gulp up all the memory it can get. You cannot limit SQL Server **without** setting a `max server memory` (that's the exact REASON that this setting exists!)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will cache esentially everything it can in order to avoid (slow) disk access. So, as your instance is used, SQL starts saving commonly used objects in the buffer, until the the allotted memory is full.